# How to remove outliers correctly and define predictors for linear model?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn

I am learning how to build a simple linear model to find a flat price based on its squared meters and the number of rooms. I have a .csv data set with several features and of course 'Price' is one of them, but it contains several suspicious values like '1' or '4000'. I want to remove these values based on mean and standard deviation, so I use the following function to remove outliers:

```
 import numpy as np
 import pandas as pd

 def reject_outliers(data):
    u = np.mean(data)
    s = np.std(data)
    data_filtered = [e for e in data if (u - 2 * s < e < u + 2 * s)]
    return data_filtered
```

Then I construct function to build linear regression:

```
def linear_regression(data):
    data_filtered = reject_outliers(data['Price'])
    print(len(data)) # based on the lenght I see that several outliers have been removed
```

Next step is to define the data/predictors. I set my features:

```
features = data[['SqrMeters', 'Rooms']]
target = data_filtered

X = features
Y = target
```

And here is my question. How can I get the same set of observations for my X and Y? Now I have inconsistent numbers of samples (5000 for my X and 4995 for my Y after removing outliers). Thank you for any help in this topic.

Comment: When you remove from Y, you need to remove corresponding entry from X

Comment: can you give me this data, i would also like to practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The features and labels should have the same length

and you should pass the whole data object to reject_outliers:

```
def reject_outliers(data):
 u = np.mean(data["Price"])
 s = np.std(data["Price"])
 data_filtered = data[(data["Price"]>(u-2*s)) & (data["Price"]<(u+2*s))]
 return data_filtered
```

You can use it in this way:

```
data_filtered=reject_outliers(data)
features = data_filtered[['SqrMeters', 'Rooms']] 
target = data_filtered['Price']
X=features
y=target
```

Comment: Thanks! Your solution looks reasonable. But do you know, why I am getting TypeError: string indices must be integers in this line? data_filtered = [e for e in data if (u - 2 * s < e["Price"] < u + 2 * s)]

Answer (score 1):

Following works for Pandas DataFrames (data):

```
def reject_outliers(data):
    u = np.mean(data.Price)
    s = np.std(data.Price)
    data_filtered = data[(data.Price > u-2*s) & (data.Price < u+2*s)]
    return data_filtered
```